# Comparison principle using truncation for porous medium equation

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

For a porous medium equation (eg. $u_t - \Delta \Phi(u) = f$), is it possible to obtain a comparison principle for very weak solutions (eg. if $u_0 \geq 0$ and $f \geq 0$ then $u \geq 0$ a.e.) using truncation functions $T_k(x) = x\chi_{[-k,k]} + k\chi_{(k, \infty)} -k\chi_{(-\infty,-k)}$?

I obtained a continuous dependence result this way. I don't want to use a duality method.

**Edit** by very weak solutions I mean $u \in L^2(0,T;H^1)\cap H^1(0,T;H^{-1})$ so we have no good control on the time derivative.

Comment: I don't think you can really avoid dual methods if you only have very weak solutions... Indeed any weak formulation for sub/super/solutions involve laplacians of test functions, which behave very badly if you plugin the truncations (one expects Dirac delta singularities on the level sets $u=\pm k$ in $\Delta T_k(u)$, right?). Why can't you just rely on the "standard" comparison principle? (which indeed holds for very weak solutions)

Comment: I see. If we suppose $\nabla u$ to exist so we don't need to worry about the Laplacian. I think under this condition it may be hopeful. 

I want to work on a different equation where the standard method is not amenable so I want to try this method.

Comment: Well, typically you may want to assume something about $\nabla \Phi(u)$ rather than for $\nabla u$, and the information one usually either assumes or gets somehow is $\nabla\Phi(u)\in L^2(0,T;L^2)$. This means that you're actually considering weak energy solutions, not just very weak solutions. That's why I was saying that dual methods seem to be in order here (at least to the best of my knowledge).